# How do objects narrow types correctly

Tags: typescript

When I use `keyof` to identify the parameters of function, its return value does not narrow the parameter correctly

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4wLwwN4CgYwGYggBcMAFAiWAK5wBGApgE4CUaAfDAgDQ4y0KMS5SjQaMufEXSatUHBDADUfHgF8A3Fix4qYYFACW4fGFIBregE8iFyyDwwolpPXvxkrbLkb0oVRmDuSADatgC6mqpaeKYA5AQgscykAIzMmkA)

```js
const map = {
  foo: (a: number) => a,
  bar: (a: number, b: number) => a + b,
};

function fn(key:keyof typeof map) {
  return map[key];
}

// Error: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
fn('foo')(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the function generic so that the type of the argument passed to the function gets reflected in the return type that TypeScript can infer.

```
const map = {
  foo: (a: number) => a,
  bar: (a: number, b: number) => a + b,
};

function fn<T extends keyof typeof map>(key: T) {
  return map[key];
}

fn('foo')(1);
```